# JQuery AJAX call from FirefoxOS falls to the error part but it does work fine

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox-os

My task is simple that I am sending string to the server using jQuery AJAX inside a FirefoxOS App. The data is received but still it doesn't proceed to the success function and falls to the error function.

Following is the segment from manifest:

```
"permissions": {
    "systemXHR": {
        "description": "Required to make Ajax Calls over the Network"
    }
},
"type": "privileged"
```

My Ajax function:

```
$('#btn_save_server').click(function() {
    contacts = 'a line of text';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/save_contacts.php',
        xhrFields: { mozSystem: true },
        data: { contacts: contacts },
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log( contacts );
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('done');
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert('error');
            console.log( request );
            console.log( status );
            console.log( error );
        }
    });
});
```

And my server:

```
<?php
    $contacts = $_POST['contacts'];
    $contacts = json_encode( $contacts );
    file_put_contents( 'contacts.txt', $contacts );
    echo 'Finished';
```

Comment: use `done:` or `complete:` instead of `success:` and see if that fixes it

Comment: Where and how do you see that the data is received ?

Comment: @jfoucher after running it the text file on the server contacts.txt has the text 'a line of text'

Comment: that's not right, if you're json_encoding stuff than surely what is in the file should be json_encoded. What do you get in the console in your error callback ?

Comment: @AminJafari the `complete` block is not a replacement for `success` as mentioned in the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @jfoucher the line `$contacts = json_encode( $contacts );` is irrelevant

Comment: here is an example based on the boiler plate app and the html5 rocks jQuery XHR examples, that uses a get : https://github.com/JasonWeathersby/FirefoxOSSystemXHR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by searching the Internet and with some help from the link provided by @JasonWeathersby

The manifest and the server code is the same. The change required was before calling the `$.ajax()` method some settings were required:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    if (options.xhrConstructParam) {
        options.xhr = function() {
            return new window.XMLHttpRequest(options.xhrConstructParam);
        }
    }
});

//for FirefoxOS (require "mozSystem" param in AJAX calls)
var xhrConstructParam = null;
xhrConstructParam = {
    mozSystem: true
};

//default settings for AJAX methods
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrConstructParam: xhrConstructParam
});
```

Since the `mozSystem` has been provided so it is no longer required in `$.ajax()` method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://www.local/mobile-sync/save_contacts.php',
    data: { contacts: contacts },
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('done');
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
        alert('error: ' + request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not return the result back to Ajax. There is not return statement at the end of your PHP file.

```
<?php
$contacts = $_POST['contacts'];
$contacts = json_encode( $contacts );
file_put_contents( 'contacts.txt', $contacts );
echo 'Finished';

return $contacts;
```